# Is it dangerous to have a cast operator on a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

We have an extensive code base which currently uses raw pointers, and I'm hoping to migrate to unique_ptr.  However, many functions expect raw pointers as parameters and a unique_ptr cannot be used in these cases.  I realize I can use the get() method to pass the raw pointer, but this increases the number of lines of code I have to touch, and I find it a tad unsightly.  I've rolled my own unique_ptr which looks like this:

```
template <class T>
class my_unique_ptr: public unique_ptr <T>
{
  public:

    operator T*() { return get(); };
};
```

Then every time I provide a my_unique_ptr to a function parm which expects a raw pointer, it automagically turns it into the raw pointer.

Question: Is there something inherently dangerous about doing this?  I would have thought this would have been part of the unique_ptr implementation, so I'm presuming its omission is deliberate - does anyone know why?

Comment: well, you can try `cout << my_unique_ptr<int>() << endl;`

Comment: See [this general answer](http://herbsutter.com/2012/06/21/reader-qa-why-dont-modern-smart-pointers-implicitly-convert-to/) by Herb Sutter, chair of the international C++ standardization committee and lead architect (or something) of the Visual C++ team at Microsoft

Comment: The blog post in question was posted today. Now that's timing.

Comment: In general, implicit conversions are bad. Types exist for a reason, conversions should be explicit.

Comment: @GManNickG: if only they'd known that back when Ritchie defined a squillion implicit conversions among the built-in types.

Answer (score 8):

There's a lot of ugly things that can happen on accident with implicit conversions, such as this:

```
std::unique_ptr<resource> grab_resource() 
{return std::unique_ptr<resource>(new resource());}

int main() {
    resource* ptr = grab_resource(); //compiles just fine, no problem
    ptr->thing(); //except the resource has been deallocated before this line
    return 0; //This program has undefined behavior.
}
```

Comment: Whoa, I did not expect this to be the most up-voted answer, since others have really good descriptions.

Answer (score 5):

It is the same as invoking the `get` on the `unique_ptr<>`, but it will be done automatically.  You will have to make sure the pointer is not stored/used after the function returns (as `unique_ptr<>` will delete it when its lifetime ends).

Also make sure you don't call `delete` (even indirectly) on the raw pointer.

Yet another thing to make sure is that you do not create another smart pointer that takes ownership of the pointer (e.g. another `uniqe_ptr<>`) -- see delete note above

The reason for `unique_ptr<>` not doing the conversion for you automatically (and have you call `get()` explicitly) is to ensure you have control over when you access the raw pointer (to avoid the above issues that could happen silently otherwise)

Comment: If nothing else, the lack of a conversion prevents the newbie catastrophe `unique_ptr<int> up(new int()); delete up;` from compiling :-) I can't immediately think of any non-newbie-error circumstances in which someone would incorrectly `delete` a pointer whose resource they don't own, and where the need to call `get()` prevents them from doing so.

Answer (score 2):

The main "danger" in providing an implicit conversion operator (to a raw pointer) on a `unique_ptr` stems from the fact that `unique_ptr` is supposed to model single-ownership semantics.  This is also why it's not possible to copy a `unique_ptr`, but it can be moved.

Consider an example of this "danger":

```
class A {};

/* ... */

unique_ptr<A> a(new A);

A* a2 = a;
unique_ptr<A> a3(a2);
```

Now *two* `unique_ptr`s model single-ownership semantics over the object pointed to, and the fate of the free world  -- nay, the **universe** -- hangs in the balance.

OK, I'm being a bit dramatic, but that's the idea.

As far as workarounds go, I would normally just call `.get()` on the pointer and be done with it, being careful to recognize a lack of ownership on what I just `got()`.

Given that you have a large, legacy code-base that you are trying to migrate to using `unique_ptr`, I think your conversion wrapper is fine -- but only assuming you and your co-workers don't make mistakes in the future when maintaining this code.  If that is a possibility you find likely (and I normally would because I'm paranoid), I would try to retrofit all existing code to call `.get()` explicitly instead of providing an implicit conversion.  The compiler will happily find all the instances for you where this change needs to be made.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it dangerous to have a cast operator on a unique_ptr?

**Edited** see comments

<sup><strike>---No, it certainly should not be dangerous---:</strike></sup> in fact the standard requires an <strike>implicit</strike> `explicit` conversion to *'safe bool'* (see [Safe Bool Idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html)).

Explanation for edit:

The new standard (also introducing unique_ptr) introduced **`explicit operator T()`** casts. It still works for unique_ptr *as if* it were an implicit conversion, in that `if`, `while`, `for(;x;)` does *automatic* contextual conversion to bool.

In my defense, my knowledge was largely based on C++03 libraries like [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) which *do* define the conversion to `unspecified-bool-type` *implicit*.

I hope this is still informative to anyone else.

---

(see the other answers for more canonical treatment, including the conversion to raw pointer)

Comment: The OP asked specifically about a cast operator to `T*`.

Comment: That's not true, the Standard mandates an *explicit* conversion to `bool`, which relies on contextual conversions to `bool`.

Comment: @HighCommander: Well I might it very very explicit what question I answered. It _is_ the title of the question. However, @LucDanton has a far better point. I wasn't (`consciously`) aware that usage in certain context would actually trigger _explicit_ conversions to bool. Mmm. Learned something today :)

Comment: Well, blimey: turns out c++11 **`explicit operator T()`** casts were new to me, that explains my wrong assumption, a bit. See **[http://ideone.com/yqrOH](http://ideone.com/yqrOH)** for a demonstration of the effect: use in `if`, `while`, `for(;x;)` does _automatic_ contextual conversion to bool. Thanks @LucDanton